# Filter spark CassandaRow each row of a RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I've a following code :-

```
 val rss = sc.cassandraTable("db", "table").select("id", "date", "gpsdt").where("id=? and date=? and gpsdt>? and gpsdt<?", entry(0), entry(1), entry(2) , entry(3))

    rss.foreach { records =>
      {
        println("Cassandra Row " + records.toString())
        val gpsdttime = records.get[String]("gpsdt")
        val justLess = rss.filter(row => row.get[String]("gpsdt") < gpsdttime).sortBy(row => row.get[String]("gpsdt"), false).take(1)
      }
    }
```

So, my idea is to pick one set of RDD from Cassandra based on some where clause and iterate through each row and find its respective previous row to re-calculate some value and update the present row. But this gives an error :-

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases: 
(1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
(2) When a Spark Streaming job recovers from checkpoint, this exception will be hit if a reference to an RDD not defined by the streaming job is used in DStream operations. For more information, See SPARK-13758.
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$sc(RDD.scala:89)
```

Suggestions please, Thanks,

Comment: You can't have rdd inside another rdd.

Comment: You could do rdd.filter(filterFunc).map(mapFunc).take(1)

Comment: @Knight71 - I understand that I cannot use RDD inside another RDD , but you know my case that I want to iterate on each RDD value and that particular row will again have to search in that RDD. and the example that you have provided rdd.filter .. will that work on iteration ?

Answer (score 0):

the meaning of the Exception is that SparkContext inited in driver but the func in foreach run in executor， so when you run the job , it will threw 
the following Exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext.
```

and the reason of your case is (1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Comment: Hi.. Kevin thank you for your response. But It'll be more helpful if you 
can provide me with some solution on how and what I can change in my code to get it resolved. Thanks,

Comment: if you want to use previous row  and update the present row, i think you can save the previous row in storage(hdfs,mysql) by a spark job, then use it by another spark job.

Comment: not exactly kevin , that will create an overhead. I'm trying to get it solved by indexing the RDD and fetching result. Lets see how it goes . meanwhile any more suggestions are welcomed. Thanks,